# Securing wine cellar vents

Tags: concrete, basement, windows

This may be a bit of the beaten path but here goes.

I have a 150+ year old wine cellar in my yard with venting on the top. These vents are large, roughly 2x4 feet. They are also stone and rough hewn ending below ground level. Some are covered over with sticks and dirt, others open.

I'm concerned that these openings are a danger to kids and pets - it's a 20+ for drop.

How can I safely cap these off while still providing lighting / venting?

Comment: You'll probably want some steel mesh. Photos seem like a requirement here.

Comment: @isherwood yeah.. I'll need to take more I just got a new phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to form up and pour/trowel a concrete frame to hold a steel grate. You should be able to find a local fabricator/welder who can make them custom to your size needs, or an internet search will reveal fabricators who will make and ship them to you.

[image]

Another option would be to build a wood version yourself. I believe you could build a "slatted cover" that would be plenty strong, but it would not provide as much ventilation as a steel grate and would require some frequency of maintenance. It *would* be significantly easier and cheaper, however.

[image]